# How to create a column 'mapping' that still works in SQL queries?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a very simple model as below:

```python
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    role = db.Column(db.String(64))
```

and then a simple query that I'm using in my view to filter users by roles:

```
roles = list(map(str, query_params.get('roles', [])))
User.query.filter(User.role.in_(roles))
```

Roles start with a capital letter ('Director', 'Manager', etc...) and I want to add a mapping to the column which returns it in lower case.
I thought `column_property()` or `@hybrid_property` would do the job but I'm either wrong, or I'm making a mistake in the implementation.

I tried these changes:

```
@hybrid_property
def role_tag(self):
    return self.role.lower()

User.query.filter(User.role_tag.in_(roles))
```

The property indeed returns the lower case value, but it doesn't work in the query raising this exception:

`AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with User.profile_role has an attribute 'lower'`

I then tried to change the model as such:

```
role_tag = column_property(role.lower())
```

which instead raise another exception on the Model directly.

`AttributeError: Neither 'Column' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'lower'`

I understand the issue is related to how they operate, if at class or instance level... But in the end I haven't been able to find the correct implementation for my use case.

Comment: In both cases you need to wrap the SQL expression in a call to what ever is your databases function for lowercasing a string using `func`.

Comment: I know I can do that in the query SQL with func.lower(). But in that case I will not need to create neither a `property_column()` or `@hybrid_property`. The point of my question is how to map a 'virtual' column to a different one so that it returns the lowercase version of the original one.

Comment: No, the idea would be to wrap it with `func.lower()` in the hybrid property's expression part. Much like you're trying to call `.lower()` on it at the moment.

Comment: DAMN!!! So simple... Of course!!! I'm not sure why I didn't think about it. Sometimes it is right in front of you and you can't see it! :D Thank you so much! Do you wanna create an answer so that I can accept it? Btw... I'm struggling to fully understand the difference between the two. Is there any real benefit in using one or the other in my case?

Comment: Update, it doesn't work. I'm probably doing something wrong. I created the `role_tag` @hybrid_property in the Model like this: `return func.lower(self.role)` but in the view it returns this string `lower(:lower_1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to define the behaviour separately for instance and class context, or Python and SQL context:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    role = db.Column(db.String(64))

    @hybrid_property
    def role_tag(self):
        return self.role.lower()

    @role_tag.expression
    def role_tag(cls):
        return db.func.lower(cls.role)
```

Comment: Hi Ilja, I'm accepting the answer but as a reference for other developers, the alternative with column_property works equally well and need only one line: `role_tag = column_property(func.lower(role))`.